# CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build is ambiguous

Tags: java, caching, guava, ambiguous

I'm trying to use a snippet of code for a Stash plugin, but the compiler keeps giving me an error that I can't seem to solve. It's using com.google.common.cache.Cache (Guava)

```
 static final RepositorySettings DEFAULT_SETTINGS = new RepositorySettings(0);
 private final PluginSettings pluginSettings;

 private final Cache<Integer, RepositorySettings> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(
        new CacheLoader<Integer, RepositorySettings>()
 {
    @Override
    public RepositorySettings load(@Nonnull Integer repositoryId)
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, String> data = (Map) pluginSettings.get(repositoryId.toString());

        return data == null ? DEFAULT_SETTINGS : deserialize(data);
    }
});
```

The .build is giving me the following error

```
The method build(CacheLoader<? super Integer,RepositorySettings>) is ambiguous for the type CacheBuilder<Object,Object>
```

Comment: `Cache` has a `build()` method that takes no parameters, `LoadingCache` on the other hand has a `build()` method that takes `CacheLoader` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Cache has a `build()` method that takes no parameters, `LoadingCache` on the other hand has a `build()` method that takes `CacheLoader` as a parameter.

```
private final LoadingCache<Integer, RepositorySettings> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(
                      new CacheLoader<Integer, RepositorySettings>() {
    @Override
    public RepositorySettings load(@Nonnull Integer repositoryId) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Map<String, String> data = (Map) pluginSettings.get(repositoryId.toString());

    return data == null ? DEFAULT_SETTINGS : deserialize(data);
    }
});
```

This should work.

As reference:
http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html

Comment: The only thing that changed is the type of the cache variable, right? I pasted your code over mine and it's giving me the same error.

Comment: I just read the reference you posted. It says "Since 10.0". Eclipse is showing me three build methods, one that has no parameters and two that take a CacheLoader parameter (one return Cache, the other LoadingCache). The javadoc I read in Eclipse seems to be version 11.0. Both methods taking the CacheLoader parameter are marked as deprecated though.

Comment: @Amaranth I tried reproducing the ambigious message, (using Guava 18.0 downloaded from Maven central (using Netbeans)) , but it's not giving me one, not with your code nor with mine.